# Paypal 'Pay now' button with contact form in wordpress

Tags: paypal, wordpress, paypal-buttons

I'm trying to build a form in wordpress with few contact details like name, phone, email, amount and then 'pay now' button. Checked with few plugins but no use. I tried integrating with CF7 but I got only paypal ID and without paypal button code, I want to do it. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow: [This](http://en.support.wordpress.com/paypal/) link to get your paypal button code.

Using contact form 7 plugin, edit your contact code (same place where you get shortcode).  Here is an example for you.  You can append to a style sheet to increase looks.  Of course, update the paypal button code I listed below to reflect the code you received following the guide I provided.

```
<ul id="contact">
<li><span class="text">Your Name</span><span class="required">(*)</span> [text* your-name]</li>

<li><span class="text">Your Email</span><span class="required">(*)</span>[email* your-email] </li>

<li><span class="text">Subject</span>[text your-subject] </li>

<li id="message"><span class="text">Your Message</span>[textarea your-message] </li>

<img alt="Buy Now Button" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_buynow_LG.gif" />


<li id="submit">[submit "Send"]</li>
</ul>
```