# Wordpress: Contact form only after paypal donate?

Tags: wordpress, paypal, contact-form-7

For my wordpress site, I would need a page with a paypal donating button, and after the user donates at least a certain amount, they are taken to a contact form(contact form 7 I've already made). 
This question is similar to [Paypal 'Pay now' button with contact form in wordpress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20112246/paypal-pay-now-button-with-contact-form-in-wordpress) and others like it, but I need the form to come up after the donation, not in the process.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1)Create a page with the contact form 
2) you can redirect user to a page after a success payment.so  redirect user to that page with the contact form.

if you are going to create a paypal donation button with a plugin, take a look at your plugin settings page. most plugins have that redirect option.if you not doing it with a plugin you can set it from your paypal account application settings.